# Cookie duplicated in document.cookie

Tags: javascript, .net, cookies, internet-explorer-9

client = IE9, server = asp.net (a sharepoint application page to be exact)

In the `Page_Load` method of a page, I have the following code:

```
Response.Cookies["XXXXX"].Value = tabtitles.IndexOf(Request.Params["tab"]).ToString();
Response.Cookies["XXXXX"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

My cookie logic wasn't behaving as expected, so using the Console in IE Developer Tools I've found that `document.cookie` had the following value:

```
>> document.cookie
    "XXXXX=3; WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={7da6dcd3-28b6-4c8f-b507-6fa80a16143c}; databaseBtnText=Open%20with%20Access; databaseBtnDesc=Works%20with%20items%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Access%20database%2E; XXXXX=7"
```

as you can see, the cookie was appended to the end of `document.cookie` instead of replaced. is this a bug in IE9? How can I correctly set and get the cookie i want?

Comment: case sensitive I doubt you are using XXXXX can you give the real Id? or just check it.

Comment: No, there's not a bug in IE here. If there were, it would have broken the web. A common source of this problem is when a cookie is set on example.com and then reset on www.example.com. Visiting www.example.com sends BOTH versions.

Comment: yes, I have checked that "XXXXX" is exactly the same in both instances.

Comment: @EricLaw, that is not possible since this web site is an Intranet and has no subdomains. Could potentially be file path though...

Comment: Interesting. Do you ever specify a `PATH` or `SECURE` attribute on the cookie? If you hit F12 and click Tools > View Cookie Information, do you see the cookies listed individually?

Comment: It was the file path. I had previously set cookies via jquery cookie plugin which had given the complete filepath in the cookie, whereas .Net had given the filepath of the cookie to be "/". Will post my own answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had earlier set a cookie with the jquery plugin, which sets the current path as that path for the cookie. The above .Net code sets the path of the added cookie to `"/"`, so there was two different cookies present, which was invisible to me when viewing the `document.cookies` variable. My solution was to set the path of the jquery cookie to be `"/"`.